# App performing AsyncTask each time orientation switches

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have a problem with the current implementation of my app. I execute an asynctask onActivityCreated but I'm not interested in doing this if the user simply changes the orientation of the phone. What is the proper way of making sure that unnescesarry asynchronous calls aren't made when the user changes the orientation of the phone?

Here are the two methods onActivityCreated and populateList. populateList is called onPostExecute().

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    userControl = new UserController(getSherlockActivity());
    lv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.callforwardlist);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    callForwardList = new SimpleAdapter( 
            getSherlockActivity(), 
            list,
            R.layout.callforward_items,
            new String[] { "line1","line2" },
            new int[] { R.id.callforward_item_text, R.id.callforward_number } );

    new PullInfoTask().execute();

    lv.setAdapter( callForwardList );

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   // *snip*

  });

}



    private void populateList() 
{

    cfinfo = userControl.GetCallForwardInfo();

    if(Integer.parseInt( cfinfo[0]) == 1)
        addItem("Viderestilling altid", cfinfo[1]);
    else
        addItem("Viderestilling altid", "Slået fra");
    if(Integer.parseInt(cfinfo[2]) == 1)
        addItem("Viderestilling ved optaget", cfinfo[3]);
    else
        addItem("Viderestilling ved optaget", "Slået fra");
    if(Integer.parseInt(cfinfo[4]) == 1)
        addItem("Viderestilling ved intet svar", cfinfo[5]);
    else
        addItem("Viderestilling ved intet svar","Slået fra");

    // Timeout Item
    addItem("Timeout",cfinfo[6]);

      callForwardList.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to stop that using,

`android:configChanges="orientation"` declare this attribute in `Manifest` file for that `Activity`.

Adviceable is that to not to use this and handle orientationChange by yourself in code.

using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` for a complete tutorial you can go through **[this Blog](http://www.gitshah.com/2011/03/how-to-handle-screen-orientation_28.html)**. also **[read here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)** on developer site.

Comment: Thanks. The blog post was very helpful.

Comment: Looks like I jumped the gun on this one. onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() doesn't exist because the class from which I am trying to override it extends Fragment. Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in the manifeast file for your activity

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Answer (score 0):

When ever phone changes its orientation, the current activity is destroyed and a new one is created with new resources (if any). So that's the default behavior of Android. However you may avoid it by telling the VM that you'll handle orientation changes manually by adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity in manifest.